# Can I call a macro right inside the struct body?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I'm relatively new to Rust and I'm exercising with macros.

The goal is to archive some sort if React-ish syntax within Rust lang.

I’m aware of the drastic DSL approach like `jsx!(<div />)`, which is a good solution but of another topic. I’m seeking something in the middle, more like Flutter or SwiftUI syntax, which leverages the native language feature as much as possible, but still presents a visually hierarchical code structure.

Here I'm exploring the idea of constructing a `View` struct using a `children!` macro.

My main intension here is to enable `View.children` field to hold an arbitrary arity tuple. Since variadic generic tuple is not available in Rust yet, macro seems to be the only option.

See the code and comment:

```rust
struct View<T> {
  // children field holds arbitrary nullable data
  // but what i really want is Variadic Tuple, sadly not available in rust
  children: Option<T>,
}

// `children!` macro is a shorthand for Some(VariadicTuple)
// so to avoid the ugly `Some((...))` double parens syntax.
macro_rules! children {
  ($($x:expr),+ $(,)?) => (
    Some(($($x),*))
  );
}

fn main() {
  let _view = View {
    children: children!(
      42,
      "Im A String",
      View {
        children: Some(("foo", "bar")),
      },
    ),
  };
}
```

So far so good. Now there's this final part I really want to further optimize:

`View {` <s>children:</s> `children!(...) }`

Is it possible to call a macro right inside the struct body, (instead of at the `value` position after a `field:` syntax) so to eliminate the need to write `children:` field redundantly?

Comment: No, but you can let the macro generate the whole struct instantiation, including `View { }`.

Comment: Thanks Sven! I am aware of this approach. Just want to investigate other options.

Comment: Is there anything about the approach of making `view!(42, ...)` generate the whole thing that you don't like? That would be helpful to know to understand what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Current example I use only one `View`. But to target React-ish usage it’d be like `Window { TopBar { Content {} } }`, multiple possible structs. Map to your suggested approach, it’d be like `view!(Window, view!(TopBar, view!(Content)))`. Visually that’s not optimal syntax.

Comment: And other reason I’d like to stay closer to idiomatic rust, is that I don’t want to invalidate language support, IDE hints etc, because of heavy use of macros.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. You can not create something exactly as you describe but you can do something very very similar.

You can implement a `new` function for the View struct like so:

```rust
struct View<T> {
  // children field holds arbitrary Option<data>.
  children: Option<T>,
}

impl<T> View<T> {
  pub fn new() -> Self {
    Self {
      children: children!(
      42,
      "Im A String",
      View {
        children: Some(("foo", "bar")),
      },
    )
    }
  }
}

// `children!` macro is a shorthand for Some(VariadicTuple)
// so to avoid the ugly `Some((...))` double parens syntax.
macro_rules! children {
  ($($x:expr),+ $(,)?) => (
    Some(($($x),*))
  );
}
```

And then to create a view object you would do this:

```rust
fn main() {
  let _view1 = View::new();
  let _view2 = View::new();
  let _view3 = View::new();

  // _view1, _view2, and _view3 are *exactly* the same
}
```

Or if you want to add arguments, something like this with some modifications for your use case:

```rust
struct View<T> {
  // children field holds arbitrary Option<data>.
  children: Option<T>,
}

impl<T> View<T> {
  pub fn new(age: i32, string: &str) -> Self {
    Self {
      children: children!(
      age,
      string,
      View {
        children: Some(("foo", "bar")),
      },
    )
    }
  }
}

// `children!` macro is a shorthand for Some(VariadicTuple)
// so to avoid the ugly `Some((...))` double parens syntax.
macro_rules! children {
  ($($x:expr),+ $(,)?) => (
    Some(($($x),*))
  );
}
```

And then implementing it:

```rust
fn main() {
  let _view1 = View::new(42, "Im A String");
  let _view2 = View::new(35, "Im another string");
  let _view3 = View::new(12, "This is yet another string");

  // _view1, _view2, and _view3 are *not* the same because they have differing "age" and "string" attributes.
}
```

I am here to help if this is not what you are looking for or if you want more help.

Comment: Appreciate it! But not what i want. I edit OP to emphasize that i expect `children!` to accept arbitrary arity params. `new` as a function can’t do that. But then again, if `new` can be turned into a macro like `View::new!()` then it’s a solution!

Comment: Can we define a macro as a member of some struct? Like `View::new!(...)`?